# PHP Session issue? Log-out, and Log-back-in; Session completely wiped

Tags: php, session, logging, authentication, logout

My PHP Sessions are giving me yet another headache.

I have just created a log-out page in my PHP code.

when the user clicks on the link, he is logged out of the system.

I got my code from several PHP manuals online.

The code works fine.  No problem.............except for this :  when the user logs back into my website, **the previous session has been wiped out!**  Meaning, when the "**Main page**" displays, it is missing almost all the necessary variables  (such as :  firstname, lastname, etc...........mostly, the user's data, which he creates when he **REGISTERS** or the first time)

The registration itself is done in my **INDEX.PHP** file  (which is where I initiate the session : **SESSION_START()**

From there, the user is taken to the **LOGIN-PHP** file (where he logs in for the first time)

After that, all is well.

However, once he logs out.............and then tried to log back-in,  all the variables have vanished. !

I suspect that the problem is caused by the way I wrote my PHP code in the LOG_OUT.php  file :

```
<?php session_start();

unset($_SESSION);

session_destroy();

session_write_close();  

header("url=http://localhost/return_to_main_page.html");

die;

exit;

?>
```

Perhaps, using :  **UNSET, DESTROY, CLOSE, EXIT, DIE**.........all at once, may be a bit of an over-kill???   :)))))

(Kinda like shooting a mouse with a rocket-launcher)

Not sure.

"Any-hoo", my point is :

(a)  The entire process works from A to Z, but only IF everything is done in sequence ---- registration, log-in, do-your-stuff, log-out, etc.  But, after that,  if the user tried to log back in, the session is "cut-off"

(b)  Obviously, this is silly.  A user should be able to log back in whenever and wherever he wants.  (What if he registers his account on a computer at home, and tries to log-in on another computer in Australia?  DOH !)

I can't find anything similar anywhere on google, or such.  My guess would be :  my problem is so silly, and hence the solution is too obvious, that nobody has ever encountered this before

Comment: You should retrieve user data each time when user logs in and store that into sessions at the time of login. You are supposed to wipe out all session data when user logs out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for ? But unset($_SESSION); are removing all of the session ^^ And if a user logs in again, you'll just have to set the session again with the variables you want :)

Comment: when user come to index page there you check the session variable is not empty then continue else redirect using header

Comment: Sessions are not databases, a session is being made whenever you set it, and destroyed whenever you unset it, therefore, look into databases, you'll be able to save data and retrieve it from it.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.  So, if I have understood correctly :  the Session Variables which I set in the INDEX.php file..............I should also set them in the LOGIN.php file ?    But, I thought that initiating session  ---  session_start ()  ---  was supposed to take care of this ??

Answer (score 0):

Doing session_destroy() and unset ($_SESSION) and etc. may be a little overkill.

instead, just do:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 session_destroy();
 header ('location:http://localhost/return_to_main_page.html');
?>
```

That's what I do in my logout scripts.. It should work.
If not, let me know.